# How to locate the field that produces the “data type mismatch” exception?

Tags: oledb, foxpro

I have a really long insert query with more than 40 fields (from an 'inherited' Foxpro database) processed using OleDb, that produces the exception 'Data type mismatch.' Is there any way to know which field of the query is producing this exception?

By now I'm using the force brute method of reducing the number of fields on the insert until I locate the buggy one, but I guess it must be a more straight way to found it...

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really any shortcut beyond taking a guess at which 20 might be the problem, chopping out the other 20 and testing, and repeating that reductive process until you hit it.

Or alternatively looking at the table structure(s) in the DBF and making sure the field types match to the OleDB types you're using. The details of how .NET types are mapped to Visual FoxPro table field types is [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa975612(v=vs.71).aspx)

If you have access to the Visual FoxPro IDE you could probably do that a lot quicker by knocking up a little program or even just doing it in the Command Window.

Answer (score -1):

You are not telling us the language you use, so that we could possibly give a sample to handle it.

Basically what you would do is:
Get the structure,
Parse the insert statement and get values,
Compare data types.

It should be a short code to make this check.